# Laravel OrderBy by related table column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a table (A) that has a One to Many relation with another table (B).

I want to query Table A and eager load Table B with the Table A results - but I also want to sort Table A by a value in Table B.

I have tried using OrderBy in the query and also trying SortBy on the resultant collection but cannot get the Table A data to be sorted by the value found in Table B.

Example of what I have tried:

```php
$query = ModelA::with("ModelB"])->get()->sortByDesc('ModelB.sortValue');
```

Keep in mind, I am only interested in the LATEST record from Table B. So I need to query Table A and sort by a value in the LATEST records of Table B.

How can I achieve this?

<s>EDIT:</s>

The below (as suggested by @ljubadr) works pretty close, but the issue is that there are many record in Table B which means that it doesn't reliably sort as it doesn't seem to sortby the latest records in Table B. Can I have the join return ONLY the latest record for each ID?

```php
$query = ModelA::select('TableA.*')
            ->join('TableB', 'TableA.id', '=', 'TableB.col_id')
            ->groupBy('TableA.id')->orderBy('TableB.sortCol', 'desc')
            ->with(['x'])
            ->get();
```

EDIT 2:

@Neku80 answer has gotten me closest but it seems to not sort the column with the greatest accuracy.. I'm sorting a Decimal column and for the most part it is in order but in some places the items are out of order..

```php
$latestTableB = ModelB::select(['TableA_id', 'sortByColumnName'], DB::raw('MAX(created_at) as created_at'))
    ->groupBy('TableA_id');

$query = ModelA::select('TableA.*')
    ->joinSub($latestTableB, 'latest_TableB', function ($join) {
            $join->on('TableA.id', '=', 'latest_TableB.TableA_id');
        })
    ->orderBy('latest_TableB.sortByColumnName')
    ->get();
```

For example, the ordering is like:

```
0.0437
0.0389
0.0247 <-- -1
0.025 <-- +1
0.0127
```

When I delete all rows except for the 'latest' rows, then it orders correctly, so it still must be ordering with old data...

**I have found a solution:**

```php
ModelA::select('TableA.*', 'TableB.sortByCol as sortByCol')
        ->leftJoin('TableB', function ($query) {
            $query->on('TableB.TableA_id', '=', 'TableA.id')
            ->whereRaw('TableB.id IN (select MAX(a2.id) from TableB as a2 join TableA as u2 on u2.id = a2.TableA_id group by u2.id)');
        })
        ->orderBy('TableB.sortByCol')
        ->get();
```

Comment: You could use join and group by. Try something like this `$rows = ModelA::with('ModelB')->select('table_a.*')->join('table_b', 'table_a.id', '=', 'table_b.a_id')->groupBy('table_a.id')->orderBy('table_b.<column>')->get();`

Comment: You could also try use sub-query. [This article](https://reinink.ca/articles/ordering-database-queries-by-relationship-columns-in-laravel#ordering-by-has-many-relationships) might help

Comment: @ljubadr Thanks, I tried your first method but get `ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column` error.

Comment: ^^ Fixed the above, changed Strict mode to false in laravel DB config. But still not ordering by the value I need. Could this be because I need to select the LATEST records from Table B somehow as there are many records?

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to order is like this:

```
$users = User::orderBy(
    Company::select('name')
        ->whereColumn('companies.user_id', 'users.id'),
    'asc'
)->get();
```

Here we are ordering in asc order by company **name** field.

In [this article it is explained in detail](https://reinink.ca/articles/ordering-database-queries-by-relationship-columns-in-laravel).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply execute a left join query:

```
ModelA::query()->leftJoin('model_b_table', 'model_a_table.primary_key', '=', 'model_b_table.foreign_key')->orderBy('model_a_table.target_column')->get();
```

Comment: I don't think it's that simple.. that would also return the many records from Model B

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you only need TableB's ID and created_at columns:

```php
$latestTableB = ModelB::select('TableA_id', DB::raw('MAX(created_at) as created_at'))
    ->groupBy('TableA_id');

$query = ModelA::select('TableA.*')
    ->joinSub($latestTableB, 'latest_TableB', function ($join) {
            $join->on('TableA.id', '=', 'latest_TableB.TableA_id');
        })
    ->orderBy('latest_TableB.created_at')
    ->get();
```

Comment: It's gotten me close to solving it, thank you, but please see the latest edit with what is happening with your example code.